# How do I set Clink's --profile option in ConEmu?

Tags: conemu, clink

ConEmu's docs give us an elegant way of [injecting Clink](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/ConEmu_Clink). However, I'd like to specify Clink's `--profile` option ([docs](https://github.com/mridgers/clink/blob/master/docs/clink.md#configuring-clink)) so that I can keep my Clink settings alongside other config files in a common location.

Is this possible in ConEmu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `ConEmu` author [was reluctant](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/635) to externalize the integration 
with external programs such as `clink`, you should resort to using an environment variable (unless you are happy with modifying `clink` installation).

The variable named `clink_profile` can be used to specify `clink` profile's location. It has preference over the `--profile` command-line switch.

You can define environment variables in `ConEmu` settings under the  `Startup/Environment` section. You need to add something like below:

```
set clink_profile=%APPDATA%\clink\profile
```

Answer (score 1):

ConEmu "loader" just tells `cmd.exe` to execute `%ConEmuBaseDir%\clink\clink.bat` inject.

So, the solution is simple.
Rename original `clink.bat` to smth, for example `clink_load.bat`
And create your own one-line `clink.bat`

```
@"%~dp0clink_load.bat" --profile yourpath inject
```

Even better, you may install (copy all files) clink to subfolder, e.g. `%ConEmuBaseDir%\clink\vendor` and create `%ConEmuBaseDir%\clink\clink.bat` containing

```
@"%~dp0vendor\clink.bat" %*
```

There you actually may pass any desired arguments to your clink loader. Even utilizing some environment variables from [ConEmu settings](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsEnvironment.html).

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/mridgers/clink/issues/390

Comment: It's definitely not a good idea to edit ConEmu's files since they will be overwritten every time you upgrade ConEmu to a newer version.

Comment: ConEmu doesn't supply clink files via ConEmu distro. These files are put by user manually.

Comment: OK, it's not part of ConEmu but clink. Anyway, my note is still valid - it's better to not change files which are distributed with some software. Definitely if there's some other way.

Comment: I insist that using batches is more flexible way. But the answer us updated.